# How to export XML data to excel using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, excel

I have a variable that contains XML data and I need to export that into MS Excel? How can I achieve that using JavaSript and/or JQuery?

Comment: Check  this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523489/export-xml-to-excel-spreadsheet-using-javascript-classic-asp

Comment: Have a look at [http://excelbuilderjs.com/](http://excelbuilderjs.com/)

Comment: Most browsers support something like `window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + yourContent)`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code to export XML data to excel using the code from site `"codeproject"` I'm sharing the link hope with will work for you!.

[Export html table to excel using javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/433079/Export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript)